# Python Prime Number Set

Tags: python, numbers

I'm trying to write a program which will print out all the prime numbers for a given set of numbers. When I run the program written below, the shell returns 2 and 3 and nothing further. What in my program is curtailing the process?

```
def main():
    for i in range (2, 100):  #the set of numbers from which 
        if is_prime(i):       #we want our prime numbers
            print(i)

def is_prime(i):
    prem = int((i**.5)+1)               #prem is square root plus one
    for pcheck in range (2, prem):      #of i, the counter in our number set
        if i/pcheck == int(i/pcheck):
        #^numbers evenly divisible by other numbers return false
            return False
    #if they don't, it's true
    return True

main()
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: 2.4.4. Would this work in an updated version? I'm using a different computer than I usually do.

Comment: @user3366963 Eww! At least move up to [Python 2.7](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.6/).

Comment: It should work in python 3.  But checking `i % pcheck == 0` is a lot more obviously correct, as @wim mentioned

Answer (score 3):

It's your prime number function that's broken

`i/pcheck == int(i/pcheck)`

This line will be an int on left hand side already (in python 2.x).

Add `from __future__ import division` at the top of your script and you will see different results!

Comment: was python 2.x not capable of dividing floats? This worked but I'm curious as to why. Thanks also

Comment: @user3366963 Since `i` (and `pcheck`) represents an integer, like C, it uses "integer division". You could use `float(i)/pcheck` to use "floating division", for instance.

Comment: It was just a syntax difference, either the numerator or denominator had to be a float for python to coerce the result to float.  By the way, I think it is better to use the `%` operator for your divisibility test instead of division, to avoid all this nonsense in the first place  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to check whether the division answer returns int or float, I recommend you to use below code.

```
def is_prime(i):
    prem = int((i**.5)+1)               #prem is square root plus one
    for pcheck in range (2, prem):      #of i, the counter in our number set
        if str(float(i)/pcheck).endswith(".0"):
        #confirm whether the float answer ends with .0 or not
            return False
    #if they don't, it's true
    return True
```

```
str(float(i)/pcheck).endwith(".0")
```

This returns True if the division answer ends with .0

For example,

```
1.0/3 = 0.3333333333333333 In this case return False
10.0/5 = 2.0               In this case return True
```

Finally These codes including your main() function return every primes within 1 to 100.